# Change format of text

Tags: powershell, text, formatting

Currently I have the following:

```
GUID=1234
PatGUID=4567
...
```

But I need this format, because I have a large set of data:

```
GUID;PatGUID
1234;4567
...
```

I have large number of files like that to change format. I currently try to change the format using PowerShell, however, I am open to any method for reaching my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the content of the file to a hashtable, create a custom object from that hashtable, then export to CSV with a custom delimiter.

```
$ht = Get-Content 'input.txt' |
      Out-String |
      ConvertFrom-StringData

New-Object -Type PSObject -Property $ht |
    Export-Csv 'output.csv' -Delimiter ';' -NoType
```

On PowerShell v3 and newer you can simplify the code by replacing `Get-Content | Out-String` with `Get-Content -Raw` and using the `[PSCustomObject]` type accelerator instead of `New-Object`.

```
$ht = Get-Content 'input.txt' -Raw | ConvertFrom-StringData

[PSCustomObject]$ht |
    Export-Csv 'output.csv' -Delimiter ';' -NoType
```

---

If your input data contains the same keys multiple times you need to split the data into chunks and convert each of them to an object individually:

```
$list = (Get-Content 'input.txt' | Out-String) -split '\r?\n(?=GUID)' |
        ForEach-Object {
            $ht = $_ | ConvertFrom-StringData
            New-Object -Type PSObject -Property $ht
        }

$list | Export-Csv 'output.csv' -Delimiter ';' -NoType
```

`\r?\n(?=GUID)` is a regular expression that uses a positive lookahead assertion (`(?=...)`) to split the string at newlines that are followed by the string "GUID".